# Bind a class property to an instance property

Tags: c#

My hypothetical scenario:

In the New World Order, the single government mandates that all the banks should provide the same rate of interest to its customers. So all the bank should agree the rate of interest. Additionally a bank needs to have a policy
where it is open to changing(either increasing or decreasing) the interest
or not. If (at least) one bank is not open to changing the rate of interest, rate must not be modified until successful negotiations.

My C# program would look like below

```
namespace NewWorldOrder
{
    public class Bank
    {
        public static float rate;
        private bool allow_rate_modification;
        private string bankname;

        // Property
        public string Bankname
        {
            // Assume some Business Logic  is added to filter values
            // Omitting those for brevity
            get => bankname;
            set => bankname = value;
        }
        // Property
        public bool AllowRateModification
        {
            // Assume some Business Logic  is added to filter values
            // Omitting those for brevity
            get => allow_rate_modification;
            set => allow_rate_modification = value;
        }
        static Bank()
        // To set the static field at runtime
        {
            // In actual case, this value may be initialized from a db
            // Again doesn't matter how it is initialized.
            rate = 4.5f; 
        }

        // The ctor
        public Bank(string bank_name_, bool allow_modification)
        {
            Bankname = bank_name_;
            AllowRateModification = allow_modification;
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Bank rbs =new Bank("Royal Bank of Scotland",true);
            Bank lloyds = new Bank("LLoyds", true);
            Bank hsbc = new Bank("HSBC", false);
            Bank.rate = 4.7f; // This should not happen as HSBC is not open to rate change

            // Irrelevant Stuff
            // ...
            // ...
        }
    }


}
```

Long story short :

How can a static (class) property bind to one particular (usually boolean) instance property in all the instances. Or is there another logical approach
in C# by which this can be done?

<sub>**Note**: I am (very) new to C# , so please forgive me if this is complete blunder</sub>

Comment: Do you know, i was more interested in how you got the small writing for your note, i actually never knew

Comment: What do mean by bind, do you mean like check if they are all true?

Comment: @MichaelRandall Exactly . Check all instances to see if they are open to rate change. I guess I have modified the title a bit to fit more closely to the requirement

Comment: @MichaelRandall : Regarding [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54489957/bind-a-class-property-to-an-instance-property/54490004?noredirect=1#comment95786129_54489957), you may use the `<sub></sub>` to zoom out your subtle feelings. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need a list, *linq* can help you query it

```
var list = new List<Bank>()
               {
                  new Bank("Royal Bank of Scotland", true),
                  new Bank("LLoyds", true),
                  new Bank("HSBC", false)
               };
if (list.All(x => x.AllowRateModification))
{
   // all banks Allow Rate Modification 
}
```

You could use a class to manage the banks

```
public class Exchange
{
   public List<Bank> Banks { get; set; } = new List<Bank>();

   public void NegotiateRates()
   {
      while (!CanModifyRates)
      {
         // to the rate stuff in here
      }
   }

   public bool CanModifyRates => Banks.All(x => x.AllowRateModification);

}

...

private static void Main()
{
   var exchange = new Exchange();
   exchange.Banks.Add(new Bank("Royal Bank of Scotland", true));
   exchange.Banks.Add(new Bank("LLoyds", true));
   exchange.Banks.Add(new Bank("HSBC", false));

   exchange.NegotiateRates();
}
```

---

**Additional Resources**

[List Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Represents a strongly typed list of objects that can be accessed by
>   index. Provides methods to search, sort, and manipulate lists.

[Enumerable.All(IEnumerable, Func) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Determines whether all elements of a sequence satisfy a condition.

Comment: Perfect ! With containers there is a way.. But that also means that the class is not able to implement a feature it desperately needs, on its own. Hope  you get my point

Comment: Or , since this the class is effectively a blueprint, what I asked for is too much to ask for since it has no knowledge about its instances.

Comment: by containers i assume you mean variables. Personally i would steer away from a static property within the class, as it stands one bank will not innately know about another bank. maybe should should create a class called exchange that manages the banks. ill add an examaple

Comment: By containers, I meant the `List` container class.  Regarding the second point, the instances are are not innately aware about each other, so we need another layer of abstraction, in this case, the `exchange` class you suggested to implement a logic. Am I right?

Comment: You can actually implement it using just the bank class. put the list as a private static in the Bank class. add the bank to the list in the constructor and use a setter for the rate that checks if the change is allowed. But you always need a list or something similar. But i think having a second class that manages the banks makes more sense, both for code style and logic (in your case, the government controls the interest rate, so the management of the interest rate should be separate)

Comment: @x4rf41 you could probably write an answer on that, though it kind of does violate separation of concerns a little

Comment: @MichaelRandall I think it's really bad style and your suggestion is much preferable. So i won't write an answer